# How to use rspec to test named routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rspec

Given I have a named route:

```
map.some_route '/some_routes/:id', :controller => 'some', :action => 'other'
```

How do I use the routing spec file 'spec/routing/some_routing_spec.rb' to test for that named route?

I've tried this after the "describe SomeRouteController" block and it doesn't work, I get 'undefined method "helper":

```
describe SomeRouteHelper, 'some routes named routes' do
  it 'should recognize some_route' do
    helper.some_route_path(23).should == '/some_routes/23'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is in a controller spec, you can call the routing method directly, no helper needed.

```
describe SomeController do
  it 'should recognize ma routes!' do
   thing_path(23).should == '/things/23'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well, just wanted to hear someone else say I wasn't crazy, hehe...Turns out I had used nested resources, which requires the parent_child_path(23) format as opposed to the child_path(23) format.

Comment: Things change fast in RSpec - dchelimsky suggests using the route_to matcher: The route_to matcher specifies that a request (verb + uri) is routable. It is most valuable when specifying routes other than standard RESTful routes.  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher  (see also Scarver's answer to this question)

Answer (score 12):

In RSpec-Rails 2.7+ you can create a `spec/routing` directory and put your routing specs in there. See the [rspec-rails docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

there's a nice shoulda matcher for this too:

```
it { should route(:get, "/users/23").to(:action => "show", :id => 23)
```

more information on using shoulda matchers with rspec:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your controller specs with the `assert_routing` method, like so:

```
describe UsersController do
  it "should recognize a specific users#show route" do
    assert_routing("/users/23", {:controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => 23})
  end
end
```

More documentation is [here](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M000350&name=assert_routing).

Comment: Yup, that's for regular route recognition, I was looking for named route specs though. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I write the specs using RSpec2, Shoulda, and Capybara. You would save this example file in **#{Rails.root}/spec/routing/thingz_routing_spec.rb** or my preference **#{Rails.root}/spec/routing/thingz_controller_spec.rb**

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ThingzController do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      get("/thingz").should route_to("thingz#index")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Alternate syntax:

`should route(:get, '/thingz').to(controller: 'thingz', action: 'index')`